# How to call a jQuery object from within its own chain

Tags: jquery

If I had a jQuery object and wanted to call itself, is there any better way of doing that then like…

```
$("#notes").text($("#notes").data("defaulttext"));
```

I mean… I know I can do something like

```
var $notes = $("#notes");
```

to speed up things a bit, but I was just wondering if there is any variable I could use that means "the object I am currently working on", instead of manually typing in the object name again.

Comment: 2nd way is correct ,use reference to Dom element

Comment: use $(this) for current object

Comment: The $(this) method doesn't work. I actually tried that before posting my question. I was hoping for something that simple, though.

Answer (score 5):

Pass a function inside `.text()` method and in that function return your object's data attribute using `this` object

```
$("#notes").text(function(){
    return $(this).data("defaulttext")
    });
```

Or in order to be less ugly you can create a plugin using

```
$.fn.edit = function() {
this.text(this.data('defaulttext'));
return this;   //to maintain chainability
};
```

and then use like

```
 $("css_Selector").edit();
```

to change the text of element to its data-defaulttext attribute

Comment: How about this?: $("#notes").text($(this).data("defaulttext")); will this refer to #notes?

Comment: Yes that one too added see the changes,Thanks

Comment: The latter $(this) method doesn't work.  I actually tried that before posting my question.  I was hoping for something that simple.

Comment: Well you  can use the first one then

Comment: Yeah, it just gets pretty ugly when I put together a big chain of methods doing the first one.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  In my specific case, I'll be calling $("#notes").data("defaulttext") a bunch in the chain and was looking for a cleaner, more object-oriented way of doing that.